python tkinter how to setup an independent Scrollbar
My goal is to create an independent ScrollBar (not connected to any widget).
All I need to do it are:

Define the number of items to scroll through (maybe boundaries min &
max )
Intercept its state changes

No try, no idea how to do it, no answer found on the web.

Independent of what? A scrollbar is useless as a UI element if it has nothing to scroll (i.e., if nothing depends on it. It would help us if you could explain why you want this / what problem you're trying to solve.

Independent of any other widget as it's the normal use. Each change in the scrollbar will pick up a data (multi line string) to show it in a text widget. NOTE: I don't want to scroll the text widget.

It is better to use Scale widget instead for your case.

@acw1668 is right, it sounds like what you really want is a scale (a.k.a. a slider)

After reading the doc about Scale, its looks like what I want. I've try it and its suits my goal. The only issue I encounter is: how to avoid printing scales values ?

@izd: if you set label="", the value won't be displayed.

label="" is for the current value, not scale's values.

@izd: oh, my bad. I was thinking of showvalue=False.

The scrollbar has a simple interface where it will call the scroll command of an object. The object doesn't have to be a widget, it just has to supply the correct interface. The object must communicate back to the scrollbar what part of the data is visible (for example, if 50% was visible the "thumb" would be 50% of the widget height or width). This interface can be discovered by reading the scrollbar man page of the underlying tk library.
The interface is just a function that accepts either two or three arguments that look like scroll N units, scroll N pages, or moveto fraction. You can interpret those arguments however you like. Your function is responsible for calling the set method of the scrollbar to tell it what part of the virtual document is visible.
Here's a really simple example that simulates being able to see 1/10th of the total virtual document. By default it assumes there are 100 items. A "page" is considered 10 items.
import tkinter as tk

class VirtualWidget:
    def __init__(self, sb, total=100):
        self._units = 1.0/total
        self._pages = 10 * self._units

        self._sb = sb
        self._sb.set(0, self._pages)

    def yview(self, cmd, *args):
        if cmd == "moveto":
            start = max(0, float(args[0]))
            end = start + self._pages
            self._sb.set(start, end)

        elif cmd == "scroll":
            amount = float(args[0])
            units = args[1]
            start = float(self._sb.get()[0])
            end = float(self._sb.get()[1])

            incr = self._pages if units == "pages" else self._units
            start = max(0, min(.90, start + (amount * self._pages)))
            end = start + self._pages
            self._sb.set(start, end)

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_geometry("100x400")
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root)
vsb.configure(command=VirtualWidget(vsb, 200).yview)
vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
root.mainloop()


(I think my math might be a little off, but this gives the general idea)

Works fine ! I keep this solution on hand in case I can't manage to avoid displaying the scale values of the Scale widget, which is simpler to implement.

Solution: setting the font size of the Scale widget to 1 or -1. font=(None,-1,"normal") will hide the scale's values.

As said in the last comment from Bryan, simply set showvalue=False when creating tkinter.Scale widget.
